# put a partial inside a content_tag in Application Helper Function Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, partials

I have this in my view but I would like to clean it up and put it all inside a method in a helper.

I know how to put div and some content inside a content_tag. However how do I pass the partial?

```
 <% if show_content?(flash[:invitation]) %>
       <div id="invite_box">
       <%= render :partial => 'user/invite', :locals => {:user => @user } %>
       </div>
       <% elsif show_content?(flash[:confirmation]) %>
       <%= render :partial => 'user/invite_confirmation' %>
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `invite` partial should always be wrapped in an `invite_box` div, it would make sense to just put that div inside the partial.

However, you can do this in your helper:

```
def show_invite_info
  if show_content?(flash[:invitation])
    content_tag(:div, :id => "invite_box") do
      render :partial => "user/invite", :locals => {:user => @user}
    end
  elsif show_content?(flash[:confirmation])
    render :partial => "user/invite_confirmation"
  end
end
```

Then in your view just do:

```
<%= show_invite_info %>
```